# Display each column value on separate line for SELECT CLAUSE in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using **psql** on my shell, I am trying to display the output of a **SELECT CLAUSE** in a specific way.
I want each column value of my rows to be displayed on its own line.

Right now, my output looks like this (the display I don’t want):

```
Expanded display is on.
idOne   nameOne   createdAtOne
idTwo   nameTwo   createdAtTwo
```

But I want it to look like this

```
Expanded display is on.
idOne
nameOne
createdAtOne
idTwo
nameTwo
createdAtTwo
```

My command line is the following

```
psql -h hostName -d databaseName -U userName -p 5432 -c '\x on' -c "
COPY (
SELECT
  e.id,
  e.name,
  e.created_at
FROM entity_name e
) TO STDOUT
;
"
```

I would like each value of a column in a row of my table to be displayed on its own separate line.

But although I have used the `-c ‘\x on’` in my command line, and even if the sentence **Expanded display is on** is displayed, my output is still displayed the first way and not in an expanded way.

How can I do this? What am I missing?

My psql version on my remote server is **psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.6** and I am using  MAC.

(ps: if it possible, I would even like my output to look like this

```
id idOne
name nameOne
created_at createdAtOne
id idTwo
name nameTwo
created_at createdAtTwo
```

Comment: Did you try to put everything into a `.sql` script and pass that to `psql`?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS

> This command sets options affecting the output of query result tables

in other words it affects only tables displayed, while `COPY to STDOUT` shows you the output of resulting generated tsc or csv. thus `\x` does not affect it.

Also from your query - I see no need in `COPY` - you just copy from query to stdout - thus omitting `copy` and just running

```
SELECT
  e.id,
  e.name,
  e.created_at
FROM entity_name e
```

in expanded display will give expected result. You will have to `grep -v 'RECORD'` though

Comment: Thank you @Vao Tsun for your answer. It solves part of my problem since the display is perfect on my shell (Expanded way).

Actually, I want to print the output in a separate file, this is why I used the COPY.

How can I manage to copy the expanded output to a file?